# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-2, ssh

I have been successfully SSHing into raspberry pi from my computer terminal, which are both on the same LAN and connected to router with LAN wire.
But today, I am getting following message.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Raspberry is set to allow password login as well as SSH key login.
I also tried putty to login with the password. But it says

```
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

What can be the problem and how can I solve it

Comment: Try using `ssh -vv ...` and edit in the output from that.  This provides more detailed information about what went wrong.